# Swift 3 Extend Range of Specific Type

Tags: swift, foundation

Having trouble grasping what the syntax would be for extending a `Range` of a specific type/types. For example, if I only wanted to extend `Range<Double>` or `Range<Int>` or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly. It's a currently missing feature of Swift. You can get around it by using a dummy protocol:

```
protocol _Int {}
extension Int: _Int {}

extension CountableClosedRange where Bound: _Int {
    var sum: Int {
        // These forced casts are acceptable because
        // we know `Int` is the only type to conform to`_Int`
        let lowerBound = self.lowerBound as! Int
        let upperBound = self.upperBound as! Int
        let count = self.count as! Int

        return (lowerBound * count + upperBound * count) / 2
    }
}

print((1...100).sum) //5050
```

The `FloatingPoint` or `Integer` protocols may also be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but the other solutions didn't work.  This did

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound: Integer, Bound == Int {
...
}
```

just using

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound == Int {
...
}
```

worked fine in coding (code completions) but resulted in Segmentation Fault 11 during compile.